# C# how to copy file from raspberry pi 3B+ to windows local folder

Tags: c#, copy, raspberry-pi3, winscp

Manually, we can do that by opening a WinSCP and login to raspberry pi, give the permission to copy files, download that file from raspberry pi, copy it into the windows folder.
But I want to make automatically in C#. Here I am trying to implement that manual process.

```
public void OpenMyRaspberrypi(string Session_Name)
        {
            #region Create SSH_Get_Date
            if (!File.Exists(CommandFilePath))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(CommandFilePath))
                {                     
                    sw.WriteLine("cd /usr/local/myTarget.json");
                    sw.WriteLine("chmod 777 myTarget.json");                    
                }
            }
            #endregion
            strCmdText = "/C plink -load " + Session_Name + " -l username -pw password -m " + CommandFilePath;                   

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            //process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            process.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
            process.Start();
        }
```

but i don't know how to use WinSCP copy it, could anyone give me some ideas? thanks a lot.

Comment: There a WinSCP library for .NET which may help here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find a solution for myself, by using SCP (Secure Copy)

```
scp pi@192.168.0.1:myfile.txt .
```